# I have a dictionary where each value is an array. I want to see if an inputted array matches any of the values

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

My code:

```
   var chords_dict = [
        "Suspended 2" : [0, 2, 7, 99, 99, 99],
        "Major" : [0, 4, 7, 99, 99, 99],
        "Minor" : [0, 3, 7, 99, 99, 99],
        "Mix 3" : [0, 3, 4, 7, 99, 99],
        "Suspended 4" : [0, 5, 7, 99, 99, 99],
        "Add 4" : [0, 4, 5, 7, 99, 99],
        "Augmented 5" : [0, 4, 8, 99, 99, 99],
        "Diminished 5" : [0, 3, 6, 99, 99, 99],
        "Minor 6" : [0, 3, 7, 9, 99, 99],
        "Major 6" : [0, 4, 7, 9, 99, 99]
    }

//This function will take the integer notation and convert to notes relative to tonic
func get_chord(tonic: String, notes_list: Array <String>, int_1: Int, int_2: Int, int_3: Int = 99, int_4: Int = 99, int_5: Int = 99) -> (String, String){

    var tonic = 0
    var chord_notes = [tonic, int_1, int_2, int_3, int_4, int_5]

    let sorted_chord_notes = chord_notes.sort()
    let dict_values = Array(chords_dict.values)

    if contains(dict_values, sorted_chord_notes){
//Error message here: cannot invoke "contains" with an argument of list type '(Array) <[Int]>, [Int]'

    return ("Test", "test")
}


    return ("Placeholder1", "Placeholder2")

}

let (string, string2) = get_chord("C", notes_list: notes, int_1: 2, int_2: 4, int_3: 7)
```

I want to pass an array into a function to see if it matches any of the values in this dictionary, but I keep getting this error:

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using? This is very old Swift code. You should update to the latest version.

Comment: I say that because `contains` is no longer a top level function. `contains` is now a part of `Array` and so your could would be something like `dict_values.contains(sorted_chord_notes)`. And `Array<String>` is now `[String]`.

Comment: Update Xcode. Then open menu "File", "Edit", "Convert", "To latest Swift syntax". This will be a good start.

Comment: I'm on version 7.3., updated May 14, 2016

Comment: The syntax you are using is not valid in Swift 2.0. You must be on an older version.

Comment: Ok I changed the contains method to use dot notation. Is that the only thing that is out of date?